# How can I add a Turle drawing to a button that is in another button in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, canvas, python-turtle

```
import turtle
from random import randint
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import ScrolledCanvas, RawTurtle, TurtleScreen


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x500")
root["bg"]="Teal"
root.title("2.S.2.D")


def create_window():
  window = tk.Toplevel(root)
  window.geometry("400x250")
  a = tk.Button(window,text="Red", command=create_window_A)
  a.pack()
  b = tk.Button(window, text="Blue", command=create_window_B)
  b.pack()
  c = tk.Button(window, text="Green", command=create_window_C)
  c.pack()
  d = tk.Button(window, text="Grey", command=create_window_D)
  d.pack()

#Red Color
def create_window_A():
    windowA = tk.Toplevel(root)
    windowA.geometry("400x250")
    canvas = tk.Canvas(master=windowA, width=800, height=800)
    canvas.grid(padx=2, pady=2, row=0, column=0, rowspan=10, columnspan=10)
    draw = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
    def draw_square():
        brad = turtle.Turtle()
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)
    Board_Button = tk.Button(master=windowA, text="Draw_Board", bg="cyan", fg="black",    command=draw_square)
    Board_Button.grid(padx=2, pady=2, row=1, column=11, sticky='nsew')
root.mainloop()`
```

Above was one of my countless attempts. The problem is that a canvas will appear and with it a button. That button opens a turtle window and draws the desired shape (square).
However what I'm trying to achieve is that the button next to the canvas will start the command that draws the square in the canvas instead of opening another window.
There are three more colors; Blue, Green, and Gray. I just need one to be correct then i can copy and paste the rest.
Thank you very much

Comment: You should use the already created turtle `draw` instead of creating new one inside `draw_square()`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Could you kindly detail the solution?

Comment: The line `draw = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)` has already created a turtle canvas, so you should use `draw` inside `draw_square()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw the square in the canvas next to the button, you should not create another turtle object inside `draw_square()`:

```py
def create_window_A():
    windowA = tk.Toplevel(root)
    #windowA.geometry("400x250") # why create a window with size smaller than the canvas?
    canvas = tk.Canvas(master=windowA, width=800, height=800)
    canvas.grid(padx=2, pady=2, row=0, column=0, rowspan=10, columnspan=10)
    # changed draw to brad
    brad = turtle.RawTurtle(canvas)
    def draw_square():
        #brad = turtle.Turtle()  # don't create new turtle window
        # draw on the already created turtle canvas
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)
        brad.forward(100)
        brad.right(90)
    Board_Button = tk.Button(master=windowA, text="Draw_Board", bg="cyan", fg="black",    command=draw_square)
    Board_Button.grid(padx=2, pady=2, row=1, column=11, sticky='nsew')
```